# Find a subgroup of $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ of size 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

8 should be a lcm of the orders of the components of the tuple. But 6 and 4 don't have any factors that have an lcm of 8. So how is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

$S_3\times\Bbb Z_4$ has order $6\cdot 4=24$, not $12=\operatorname{lcm}(6,4)$, and $8$ certainly divides $24$. Remember, you’re looking for a subgroup of order $8$, not an element of order $8$.

Comment: GAP shows that there are 3 subgroups of order 8  with 3 generators.

Answer (score 4):

Take the element $(s,0)$  which has order $2$  and the element $(1,1)$ which has order $4$. These two elements generate a group of order $8$. When I write $(1,1)$  the first $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $S_3$, while the second $1$ is the class of $1$ in $Z_4$.

Comment: Since there are 3 elements of order 2 in $S_3$ (the three transpositions) there should be 3 such subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_4$ has order 4.  If you can find a subgroup of $S_3$ with 2 elements—call it $T_2$—then $T_2\times \Bbb Z_4$ will be a subgroup of $S_3\times\Bbb Z_4$ of order $2\times 4 = 8$.

But subgroups of order 2 of $S_3$ are easy to find, because $S_3$ contains $S_2$.